# How to use while loop to detect if the customer ID already available in the list?

Tags: python

C1 and C2 in the list_test is a customer id, so I want them to be unique.I would like the while loop to detect that C1 and C2 is already used in the list_test. I expect the code below to return 'C3' and assign the 'C3' to variable name new_customerid.

```
list_test = [['C1', 'James', 0, 100], ['C2', 'Lily', 0, 30]]

while True:
a = 0
for customer in list_test:
    if customer[0] == ('C'+str(a)):
        a += 1
        continue
    elif customer[0] != ('C'+str(a)):
        new_customerid += 'C'+str(a)
        print(new_customerid)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no gaps in the list, you could extract the numeric part of the customer ID, find the maximum one, add one, and then prepend the `C` character back to it. Using a comprehension expression, this could even be a one-liner:

```py
next_id = 'C' + str(max(int(c[0][1::]) for c in list_test) + 1)
```